# Remove duplicates from List(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, list, duplicates

How can I remove my duplicates in the `List(Of String)`? I was under the assumption that it could work with `List(Of T).Distinct`, but my result says otherwise. What am I doing wrong? Or what do I have to change to remove the duplicate items in the `List(Of T)`?

I have read something on the worldwide web about hash something, but I don't think that is really necessary.

This is my code where the list is generated (works with Autodesk Inventor).

```
Private Function CountCylinders(ByVal oDef As AssemblyComponentDefinition) As Integer

    ' Lets list all cylinder segments found in the assembly
    ' we will need the document name to do this.
    ' the initial value is nothing, if, after counting
    ' this is still the case, there are no cylinders.
    Dim oList As New List(Of String)

    ' Loop through all of the occurences found in the assembly
    For Each oOccurrence As ComponentOccurrence In oDef.Occurrences

        ' Get the occurence document
        Dim oOccurenceDocument As Document
        oOccurenceDocument = oOccurrence.Definition.Document

        ' Check if the occurence document name contains cylinder
        If oOccurenceDocument.FullFileName.Contains("Cylinder") Then
            ' Get the cylinder filename
            Dim oCylinder As String
            oCylinder = oOccurenceDocument.FullFileName

            ' Get the filename w/o extension
            oCylinder = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oCylinder)

            ' Remove the segment mark.
            oCylinder = oCylinder.Remove(oCylinder.LastIndexOf("_"), oCylinder.Length - oCylinder.LastIndexOf("_"))

            oList.Add(oCylinder)
            Debug.Print("add : " & oCylinder)
        End If
    Next

    ' Delete the duplicates in the list
    oList.Distinct()

    ' TODO: can be removed.
    Debug.Print("Total number of cylinders = " & oList.Count)

    ' Return the number of cylinders
    CountCylinders = oList.Count

End Function
```

Here is my debug output from the code:

```
add : Cylinder_1
add : Cylinder_2
add : Cylinder_2
add : Cylinder_2
add : Cylinder_2
add : Cylinder_2
add : Cylinder_7
Total number of cylinders = 7
```

Comment: shouldnt it be  Dim removedDups As New List(Of String) = oList.Distinct().ToList

Comment: `Distinct()` returns an enumerator. You could do `Debug.Print("Total number of cylinders = " & oList.Distinct().Count())`. It's probably more reasonable to use a `HashSet<T>` instead of `List<T>`.

Comment: `newList = oList.Distinct().ToList()`  Distinct is a method *returning* a new list, but it works using the default equality comparer, not just the name or some text in the object which wort of looks like what you are doing there

Comment: `Enumerable.Distinct` is a LINQ extension method which returns a sequence without duplicates(if the type overrides `GetHashCode` + `Equals` like string). Since you want to remove duplicates from your list you have to re-assign them to the list variable: `oList = oList.Distinct().ToList()`. The `ToList` creates a new list with the distinct strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the answer you're looking for thanks to dotnetperls.com [VB.NET Remove Duplicates From List](https://www.dotnetperls.com/duplicates-vbnet)

```
ListOfString.Distinct().ToList
```

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Imports System.Linq

...

Dim oList As New List(Of String)
oList.Add("My Cylinder")
oList = oList.Distinct.ToList()
```

It's necessary to include `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function RemoveDuplicate(ByVal TheList As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
    Dim Result As New List(Of String)

    Dim Exist As Boolean = False
    For Each ElementString As String In TheList
        Exist = False
        For Each ElementStringInResult As String In Result
            If ElementString = ElementStringInResult Then
                Exist = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not Exist Then
            Result.Add(ElementString)
        End If
    Next

    Return Result
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not sure why your answer got a downvote, as it works. Perhaps because there is an answer in the comments already (`oList = oList.Distinct().ToList()`). You could make your code more efficient by using `Exit For` as the line after `Exist = True` because as soon as you know the element is in the results list you don't need to check any more elements of `Result`.