# I can't remove duplicate items from a list

Tags: vb.net, loops

I've been trying to do the last part of my homework for a few days now and I'm just fed up. For my assignment, I need to take items from one list, and put them in another list sorted, which I've already done. The problem is that for the second part I need to get rid of duplicates and I can't seem to do it. Can someone please help me? I'm only up to loops. Here's the code bellow:

```
'Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    Dim Duplicate As String = lstInitial.Text
    Dim counter As Integer = 0

    lstFinal.Items.Clear()
    lstFinal.Sorted = True

    For i As Integer = 0 To (lstInitial.Items.Count - 1)
        lstFinal.Items.Add(lstInitial.Items(i))

    Next

    For n As Integer = 0 To (lstFinal.Items.Count - 1)
        lstFinal.Items.Remove(n)
    Next
End Sub`
```

Comment: if it doesn't have to be `List<>`, `SortedSet<>` is always sorted and keeps only distinct items.

Comment: contains is the method you are looking for. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732563/check-if-a-list-of-strings-contains-a-value

Comment: However, if you already have duplicates in your list check the answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349688/remove-duplicates-from-listof-t

Comment: Check .Distinct

Comment: Before writing any code, you should have an algorithm, i.e. a list of steps that the code needs to perform. You should be able follow that algorithm using a pen and paper and get the right result for various sets of test data. Only when you are at the stage of having a tested, working algorithm should you try to write code and the code must implement the algorithm. What's your algorithm? If you don't know exactly what the code is supposed to, the chances of the code you write doing it are slim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should say that your tutor isn't really showing you a good practice for the real world. It's generally better to check for duplicates before adding information to the final list.

So really the code to add data should be

```
For i As Integer = 0 To lstInitial.Items.Count - 1
    If Not lstFinal.Items.Contains(lstInitial.Items(i)) Then
        lstFinal.Items.Add(lstInitial.Items(i))
    End If
Next
```

Oh any you don't need brackets around the loop end point parameter