# List(Of String) Distinct has duplicates

Tags: string, vb.net, linq

I have this code that creates a List(Of String), each string that contains a CSV string that is parsed and separated.

The input string is in the format of : *rivaroxaban, cetirizine, furosemide, ultibro breezhalen, paracetanol, nitrofurantoin, vacomycin, thiamine, TOD*

```
 Dim dView As GridView = view1.GetDetailView(view1.FocusedRowHandle, view1.GetVisibleDetailRelationIndex(view1.FocusedRowHandle))
    Dim f = dView.GetFocusedRowCellValue("FormName")
    Dim l = dView.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Label")
    Dim path As String = "Y:\Temp\" & l & ".xls"
    Dim mylist As New List(Of String)
    Dim t As TextInfo = New CultureInfo("en-GB", False).TextInfo
    Dim myarray As String()
    Dim Lines() = PatientList.ExortValues(f, l).ToArray

    Dim delimiters As Char() = {","c, ";"c, " "c, ControlChars.CrLf}
    For Each line In Lines
        For Each item In line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            mylist.Add(t.ToTitleCase(item).Trim)
        Next
    Next

    mylist.Sort()

    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path)          
        Dim dList = mylist.Distinct
        dList.ForEach(Sub(c) writer.WriteLine(c))
        'Debug.Print(grp)
    End Using
```

When I examine the output of the StreamWriter I can see duplicates in the file

```
+-------------+
| Allopunnol  |
+-------------+
| Allopurinol |
+-------------+
| Allopurinol |
+-------------+
| Allopurinol |
+-------------+
| Allopurinol |
+-------------+
| Allopurinol |
+-------------+
| Allopurinol |
+-------------+
| Allopurinol |
+-------------+
| Allopurinol |
+-------------+
| Allopurinol |
+-------------+
| Allopurnol  |
+-------------+
```

I have also tried `Dim g = mylist.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Trim).OrderByDescending(Function(z) z.Key).Select(Function(h) h.Key)`

I feel like I am missing something but I cannot figure it out.

**Edit**: `mylist.Distinct.ToList` has no effect on the output. Duplicates still remain.

Comment: Use `HasTable(Of String)` for `myList`. It will silently skip non-distinct added items.

Comment: 1) `dList.ForEach` shouldn't even compile (unless you have a `ForEach` extension method for `IEnumerable`). 2) `mylist.Distinct()` will _always_ produce distinct values. Period. It might produce something that _looks like duplicates_ but it's actually not. My guess is that either you think there are duplicates when it's not the case or your "real" code is different. Please provide a [repro].

Answer (score 1):

It's a blind try using Linq

```
ListOfString.Distinct().ToList
```

My Reference Here : [remove-duplicates-from-listof-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349688/remove-duplicates-from-listof-t)

Comment: That shouldn't change anything here.  Leaving `dlist` as the enumerable should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicates then you probably ought to be using a `HashSet(Of String)` instead. It's `Add` method will return a `Boolean` to indicate whether the new item was added or not, which it won't be if it's the same as an existing item. One point to note is that `HashSet(Of T)` implements `ICollection(Of T)` but not `IList(Of T)`, so you can enumerate it and get the item `Count` but you cannot access items by index.

```vb
Dim myList As New HashSet(Of String)

'...

mylist.Add(t.ToTitleCase(item.Trim()))

'...

File.WriteAllLines(path, myList.OrderBy(Function(s) s))
```

Note that there is no `Sort` method on a `HashSet(Of T)` so the LINQ `OrderBy` method is used to sort instead.

Note also the call to `File.WriteAllLines` that makes writing a list of values to a text file much more succinct.